# Syntax tree of a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How would you draw the syntax tree of the sentence below?

> She arrived at quarter past two

My doubts are especially about *at quarter past two*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"at quarter past two" is a prepositional phrase, where "two" is the object, "past" is an adjective describing the two, and quarter is an adverb modifying past.

The entire prepositional phrase modifies "arrived". As an intransitive verb, it *cannot* take an object, but it can be modified.

This [article on transitive and intransitive verbs](http://www.writingcentre.uottawa.ca/hypergrammar/trnsintr.html) explains it further.

It says:

> The train from Montreal arrived four hours late.
>
> The intransitive verb "arrived" takes no direct object, and the noun phrase "four hours late" acts as an adverb describing when the train arrived.

In this instance, the difference is "at" which turns it into a prepositional phrase acting adverbially.

Comment: Probably the measure phrase _quarter past two_ is the object of _at_. _Quarter past two_ is effectively an idiom, and its parts needn't be distinguished in a phrase structure tree. _At_ is, however, governed by the nature of the measure phrase -- note _She arrived **at** 2:30 / **on** the twelfth / **in** late Spring_.